# How can I use this php empty function to properly display CSS?

Tags: php, css

I made a page where users can input a Hex Code for different colors they want to change on their page. It all works fine, but I would like to make it so if the box the user is inputting to is empty, then display the default CSS. Otherwise, display a custom one.

I'll use an example:

The users choice gets sent to a form validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('channelNameColor',
                    lang('user_themes_channel_name_color'),
                    'trim|strip_tags|xss_clean|min_length[6]|max_length[6]');
```

Then it eventually gets passed to a file where it can be used in CSS:

It is declared here:

```
$channelNameColor = $theme['channelNameColor'];
```

Then down below all those declarations it gets put in as CSS:

```
.channelNameBar h1{
font-size:20px;
color:#<?=$channelNameColor?>;
float: left;
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
<?php
if (empty($channelNameColor)){
     echo ".channelNameBar h1{";
     echo "font-size:20px;";
     echo "color:#FFFFFF;";
     echo "float: left;";
     echo "}";
}
else
 {
     echo ".channelNameBar h1{";
     echo "font-size:20px;";
     echo "color:#$channelNameColor;";
     echo "float: left;";
     echo "}";
 }
?>
```

But it is not recognizing `$channelNameColor` in: `if (empty($channelNameColor)){`

Why is it not recognizing it there, but it recognizes it fine when I use it in the css?
Sorry if this is a very simple question to answer, I'm pretty new to PHP

Comment: Maybe it *does* recognize it, but it's just that the variable isn't empty if the user didn't write anything. How about testing what the variable contains with `var_dump($channelNameColor)`

Comment: well i say it doesnt recognize it because if I type in $   in the IDE it usually shows up in the list of options as $channelNameColor, but in the `empty` function, it does not

Comment: well, IDEs aren't all-knowing, so you should test the code somehow :P

Comment: BTW, if you want you can reduce those rules to something like `is_numeric|exact_length[6]`.

Comment: Great, thank you. It turns out it was a problem with the IDE... now I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it would make more sense not to declare `channelNameColor` at all if the user input is empty. You can do this in your validation!

Then later on you can use `isset()` instead of `empty()`, which is a bit more reliable after you did your validation!

Also make sure that you include your else-statement in curly brackets, otherwise it will output it anyway!

Comment: Could I add a callback function inside my form validation? Saying to quit if there is no value to the channelNameColor?

Comment: I didnt actually use what I have up there, I wrote that on here and accidently forgot to add the braces

Comment: Sure you can, but therefore you'd need to extend/edit your validation class. I don't know what class you are using, but that should be easy. The question it what happens if the input doesn't have 6 characters and is not in the proper hex format ? If its a proper validation class it'll return false if not valid. Then just do something like 'if(!$validation) { $channelNameColor = $theme['channelNameColor']; }'

Comment: Oh I'm using code igniter and I already have all those boundaries set. But thank you! It turns out it was just an IDE error and thats why it wasnt showing up. I got it working just the way I wanted to now! But I might go ahead and look into doing it in the form validation so that the information does not have to pass through those extra steps